# How to highlight any text in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am looking for an extension that allows me to highlight anything I want on any file type (html, js, txt, etc), with any colour I choose.

Similar to [Super Simple Highlighter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio?hl=en) extension for Chrome, but for VS code.

The closest thing I found is [Text Marker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.text-marker), but that only works to highlight identical occurrences.

I want to highlight anything I want without restriction (not based on regex or syntax either).

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at `Hightlight`